# Наложение динамически созданных компонентов

Tags: c++builder, компоненты

Генерирую компоненты на форме через цикл

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    //Панель
    Pnl[i] = new TPanel(UserMain);
    Pnl[i]->Parent = UserMain;
    //---тут всякие прочие свойства компонента типа его размеры и т.д.
    //Картинка
    Img[i] = new TImage(UserMain);
    Img[i]->Parent = Pnl[i];
    //---
    //Название
    Lbl[i] = new TLabel(UserMain);
    Lbl[i]->Parent = Pnl[i];
    //---
    //Кнопка
    Btn[i] = new TButton(UserMain);
    Btn[i]->Parent = Pnl[i];
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой наложения панели на все остальные компоненты

Методы `BringToFront` и `SendToBack` не работают. Пытался изменять порядок создания компонентов, а также игрался с свойством `Parent` - положительного результата не получил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Панель и кнопка - оконные контролы, а TImage и TLabel - графические (наследники TGraphicControl). Последние не могут быть поверх оконных при общем родителе (это связано с порядком отрисовки).

Если непременно нужно так сделать - то можно положить графические контролы на отдельные панели

Дельфийский код даёт то, что положено:

```
var
  i: integer;
  pn: TPanel;
  lb: TLabel;
  im: TImage;
  bt: TButton;
begin
  for i := 0 to 3 do begin
    pn := TPanel.Create(Self);
    pn.Parent := Self;
    pn.SetBounds(i * 60, 0, 50, 50);

    im := TImage.Create(Self);
    Im.Parent := pn;;
    im.SetBounds(0, 20, 20, 20);
    im.Canvas.TextOut(0, 0, IntToStr(i*10));

    lb := TLabel.Create(Self);
    lb.Parent := pn;;
    lb.SetBounds(0, 0, 20, 15);
    lb.Caption := inttostr(i);

    bt := TButton.Create(Self);
    bt.Parent := pn;;
    bt.SetBounds(30, 0, 20, 15);
    bt.Caption := inttostr(i);
  end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я ставлю им разного родителя. Родитель кнопки и панели - форма, родитель изображения и текста - панель. Но это тоже не работает

Comment: А как именно не работает? Так, как приведено в тексте вопроса - должно отображаться без проблем-  на форме панель, на ней кнопка, image, label.

Comment: Не работает так, как в тексте вопроса. У панель родитель форма, у остальных компонентов родитель панель.

Comment: Привёл пример с такими родителями, как в вопросе - ничего никуда не накладывается. Может, c координатами что-то не то? Для дочерних они должны быть относительно родительского окна.

Comment: Проблема была в координатах, вы правы. Спасибо огромное, второй раз помогаете, надеюсь и третий раз поможете)